# SQL query doesn't execute on MSSQL

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server

The script receives variable from URL:

```
if(isset($_GET['string'])){
    $string = $_GET['string'];
}
```

Then I use this variable in sql query:

```
$sql = 
"SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    mytable
WHERE
    mytable.column_a = '".$string."'";
```

The problem is that this query doesn't execute, where my variable contains special characters. Example:

```
/myscript.php?string=a>xxx<P>yy@"
```

Tried to use both *htmlentities()* and *addslashes()*. Also tried to copy/paste *echo* of the variable - works fine.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Use query parameters instead of stuffing the value into the query string.

Comment: I would also suggest the same thing, use query parameters instead of putting the values in your php query string

Comment: If you have special characters and you take the string from URL, dont you need to use decoding?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

Comment: either you use parameters which will fix it for you, or you write a few pages of code to escape every special character.

Answer (score 1):

Please, use parameters instead of concatenate query parts. This code should work fine:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$serverName = "SERVER\INSTANCE";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"Test");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if(isset($_GET['string'])){
    $params = array($_GET['string']);
}

if( $conn === false ) {
   echo "Unable to connect.</br>";
   die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$tsql = 
"SELECT  *
FROM mytable
WHERE column_a = ?";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $params);

if( $stmt === false ) {
    echo "Error in executing query.</br>";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

while ($obj = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
    echo $obj[0]; 
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

First check $string is getting correct and then try,

```
$sql = 
"SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    mytable
WHERE
    mytable.column_a = ".$string;
```

Answer (score 0):

If column_a is nvarchar datatype try including N before the string quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use urlencode — URL-encodes  ion your codes, for more information and details you can also have a look at following link:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php